# java.lang.NumberFormatException: null java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am trying to get values from jsp page and want store those values in mysql(xampp) database using java.
The connection is established and successfully logged in but when i tried to get values null pointer exception occurs

`MainController.java` is

```
package classes;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.Date;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

//import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.Statement;

import java.sql.Time;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**

 * Servlet implementation class MainController

 */

@WebServlet("/MainController")

public class MainController extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**

     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()

     */
    public MainController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**

     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse

     *      response)

     */

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {




    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    }
    //@SuppressWarnings("null")
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String url= "jdbc:mysql://localhost/meeting_planner";
        System.out.println("start");
        // boolean stfound = false;

        try {
            System.out.println("reached controller");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "admin", "admin");

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        //System.out.println("connection");
        String button=request.getParameter("button");
        System.out.println(button +  request.getParameter("AId"));




        if(button.equals("login"))
        {

            System.out.println("inside if");

            String  AdminId= request.getParameter("AId");
            String password= request.getParameter("Password");

            System.out.println(AdminId+"  sadia   "+password);

            if(!(AdminId=="" || password==""))
            {

                boolean stfound = false;

                System.out.println(AdminId+"  sadia   "+password);

                String query = "SELECT AId,Password FROM administrator";

                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                System.out.println(query);

                while(rs.next())
                {

                    String dbadminid = rs.getString(1);
                    String dbadminpwd = rs.getString(2);

                    if(AdminId.equals(dbadminid) && password.equals(dbadminpwd))
                    {
                        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                        session.setAttribute("userid",dbadminid);
                        stfound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }




        if(stfound){
             RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher ( "/meeting_Id.jsp" ) ;

             dispatcher.forward ( request, response ) ;

            }
        }
            else{
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher ( "/index.jsp" ) ;

                dispatcher.forward ( request, response ) ;

            }
            }
        if(button.equals("Next"))
    {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String AID =(String) session.getAttribute("aid");


        int meetingid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("meeting_id"));
        /*String CNM= request.getParameter("CNM");
        int CCD = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("CCD"));
        int  CCDD= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("CCDD"));
        int PID= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("PID"));
        int STFID=Integer.parseInt(AID);*/

        meeting obj=new meeting();
        obj.addmeeting(meetingid);

        System.out.print("Sadia");

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher ( "/creat_date.jsp" ) ;

        dispatcher.forward ( request, response ) ;
    }
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

and Meeting.java is

```
package classes;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.Date;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.Time;

import java.sql.Statement;

public class meeting {

    private int meeting_id;
    Connection con=null;
    Statement smt = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public meeting()throws ClassNotFoundException//construtor
        , SQLException{
            //  try{
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/meeting_planner";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "admin", "admin");

            smt = con.createStatement();

            //}catch(ClassNotFoundException e1){
            //e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        public void addmeeting(int meeting_id1)throws ClassNotFoundException  // from attribute web.xml
            , SQLException{
                System.out.println("------TRY INSERTION------"); 


                String query = "SELECT meeting_Id FROM meeting";
                ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery(query);
                int numCols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount()+1;
                //  STAFF_ID=numCols+1;

                String query1 = "INSERT INTO Meeting VALUE ( "+meeting_id+")";
                System.out.println(query1); 
                smt.executeUpdate(query1);

            }
        }
```

the name of Next button is "next"
when i print the value of `next` in this line `System.out.println("next"+next);`
it print null for next parameter

** EDIT: The problem with NullPointerException was resolved, but now a NumberFormatException is thrown **

Console is like this

```
start

reached controller

inside if

111  sadia   sadia

111  sadia   sadia

SELECT AId,Password FROM administrator

start

reached controller

Oct 29, 2014 6:44:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [classes.MainController] in context with path [/Meeting1] threw 

exception

java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

    at classes.MainController.doPost(MainController.java:141)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

    at 

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)

    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)

    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)

    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)

    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)

    at 

org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The index.jsp is

```
<form method = "post" name="create" action="MainController">

                                    <label for="author">Enter id: </label> <input type="text"
                                        id="AId" name="AId" required="required" />
                                    <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
                                    <label for="author">Enter_password: </label><input
                                        type="password" name="Password" required="required" />
                                    <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
                                    <br>  <input type="submit"
                                            name="button" " value="login"
                                            style="height: 30px; width: 70px"></a>
                                             </input>

                                </form>
```

The meeting_Id.jsp is

```
<form method="post" name="create" action="MainController">

                    <label for="author">Enter Meeting Id:</label> <input type="text" id="meeting_id" name="mid" required="required" />
                    <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>


                    <div class="cleaner_h10"></div><br>

            <input type="submit" name="cancelbutton" value="Cancel" style="height:30px; width:70px">
            </input>
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Next" style="height:30px; width:70px">
            </input>
                </form>
```

Comment: So, what is line 72?

Comment: It looks like the code in your page is actually running twice.  Perhaps when you're doing the "forward" at the end, you're forwarding to a page that redirects to something that uses the same controller; or something like that.  I would recommend that you try stepping through this with a debugger to get a clearer picture of what's going on.

Comment: yes the pages index.jsp and meeting_Id.jsp both have form action="MainController" So what should i do ?

Comment: So how is it redirecting or resubmitting?  Or are you actually clicking something on the form when it displays the second time?

Comment: And is that an extra `"` mark in your JSP?  In the line that starts `name="button"`?  Also, I see an `</a>` without a matching `<a>`.

Comment: What about the "meeting_Id.jsp"?

Comment: index.jsp is a login form i click on login button and its forward the control to meeting_Id.jsp and there is a next button when i click on it error occurs "null pointer exception" and all that mentioned above

Comment: Then you should show us meeting_id.jsp too, because that's where the problem is.

Comment: @DavidWallace yes it was extra and </a> it was by mistake ... thank u

Comment: i edit the post to show meeting_Id.jsp code

Comment: OK, so for a start, try using the name "button" for both buttons on meeting_Id.jsp, since this is the name you're checking for.

Comment: i changed meeting_Id.jsp by name="button" and also change the MainController.java by String next=request.getParameter("button");

Comment: now it shows error when i run this java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
 classes.MainController.doPost(MainController.java:150)

Comment: in console its "start
reached controller
login111
inside if
111  sadia   sadia
111  sadia   sadia
SELECT AId,Password FROM administrator
nextlogin
Exceptions Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: If you have changed your code, please edit your question to the new code, and write the console at its botton. Most people write something like "EDIT: I changed my source and now it does so and so". You can use code blocks only in the question.

Comment: i just edit the question ....now i m using button for both jsp pages ..it shows null pointer exception and stuck in the line if(button.equals("Next")) thanks

Comment: I expanded my answer. Though I'm pretty sure the updated stack trace should have shown a NullPointerException again rather than NumberFormatException, but anyway, I covered both of them.

Comment: thank u i edit the code and edit name="meeting_id" in meeting_Id.jsp then i the run now it shows class not found exception that is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: classes/meeting

Comment: Did not see a warning yet: use a PreparedStatement; reason [hacking](https://xkcd.com/327/) and escaping of apostrophe etcetera.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution for the original NullPointerException problem

The problem is in here:

```
    //System.out.println("connection");
    String button=request.getParameter("button");
    System.out.println(button +  request.getParameter("AId"));




    if(button.equals("login"))
```

As you can see from your own debug printing, both `button` and the parameter `AId` that you print are null.

Therefore, when you try to call `button.equals("login")` you get a NullPointerException. That's because you can't call a method on a null.

You should always check if your parameters are `null` before using them. Even if you think that they should never be `null` - because hackers can try to send stuff to your servlet without the control of your form.

Here is what happens, step by step.

1. You display `index.jsp`. You click the button.
2. MainController runs. Since there is a `button` parameter that came from `index.jsp`, everything is OK, and it reaches the code at the end that forwards it into the `meeting_Id.jsp` which is now displayed on your browser.
3. You now click the button and send the form in the `meeting_Id.jsp` back to `MainController`.
4. Now, in this invocation, there is no parameter `button`. Therefore you get the NullPointerException.

You are working in an MVC environment. Every form is sent to the same controller, `MainContoller`, and `MainController` is supposed to be smart enough to know which form sent it the request, and handle it accordingly. But yours assumes only `index.jsp` is calling it. But it doesn't work like this. When you click the `next` button on `meeting_Id.jspa`, you are creating a **new request**, which goes to the same `MainController` servlet, and causes the error.

You should make sure your forms send some sort of ID that tells `MainController` which form is using it at the moment, and then the controller can send the request to be processed by the appropriate model. The input you use this for should have the same name and should exist in all the forms you are sending.

#### Solution for the NumberFormatException

Now you have a similar issue for a different reason. In this line:

```
 int meetingid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("meeting_id"));
```

You are trying to parse a parameter called `meeting_id`. The problem is that, again, you are not checking for nulls. You don't actually have such a parameter.

Why? Because this is what your HTML (in `meeting_Id.jsp`) says:

```
<input type="text" id="meeting_id" name="mid" required="required" />
```

As you can see, "meeting_id" is its **id**, not its **name**, and `getParameter()` always works with the input's `name`.

Beyond that, after you fix this, you must either make sure (with a regex) that the parameter has only numbers in it, or you have to catch `NumberFormatException` using a try-catch block around the `parseInt` line.

Always, always, check the parameters that you get from the user. Never assume that they exist, that they are not null, or that they have the values you expect them to have.

Comment: Thank u #RealSkeptic. The button is submit button and when i remove the code after the comment "//for getting meeting id" it works fine the problem starts with the line after this comment

Comment: @SadiaAsghar: the stack trace tells you exactly where the exception is thrown: at line 72. Why don't you tell us which line this is?

Comment: its if(button.equals("login"))

Comment: Well, the problem is the comparison `button.equals("login")`. You may think it is somewhere else, because it only happens when you activate the servlet again from your "meeting_Id.jsp" which is probably using the same servlet as a form `action` and doesn't have a `button`.

Comment: I extended my answer to explain the process better. It is indeed as I thought - the same action, called twice.

Comment: thank u i edit the code and edit name="meeting_id" in meeting_Id.jsp then i the run now it shows class not found exception that is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: classes/meeting

Comment: (a) Your classes should always have names that start with a Capital letter (`Meeting`, not `meeting`). (b) The public classes' names should always match the name of the file in which they are saved, including capital letters.

Comment: classes is the package name and the project name is Meeting1 where the package and classes reside

Comment: i changed package name by Meeting1 now the problem solve the control moves to meeting.java the console shows that the problem is now at INSERT INTO Meeting VALUE ( 0) after that error occurred "java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: I don't think the StackOverflow format is good for what you are trying to do here. You need to have an experienced programmer right next to you helping to point out the mistakes. So this is my last comment on this issue: the syntax of an INSERT statement is `INSERT INTO <table name> VALUES (<values of all fields>)` OR `INSERT INTO <table name> (<field1>,<field2>,...) VALUES (<value1>,<value2>,...)`.